# How to check How I installed MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mern

I am making full stack application(MERN) using MongoDB Atlas.

I want to access to mongod.conf to change some configuration on my mongoDB on my Mac OS Big Sur(Version 11.5.2).

on the internet, almost all of information says, if I installed it through Homebrew, it should be in /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf.

However I don't find it in this directory, so I must have installed it from somewhere else.

How do I know how I installed something in my mac?

Also, Is it possible that I am using MongoDB Atlas without installing them in my machine?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With brew if more easy, documentation [says](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/), first

> brew tap mongodb/brew

> brew update

> brew install mongodb-community@5.0

then you need start the service

> brew services start mongodb-community@5.0

To see the service running you need write on the terminal

> brew services list

and you will see this

[image]

It's not needed to have installed locally, you can use the free tier from MongoDB Atlas or mlab. You will need to setup the user access permission and the url where your database is stored.

Finally you can use the command "mongo" in the terminal and you will see if it's installed correctly.